# Calling virtual C++ functions with QML

Tags: c++, qml

I discovered through trial and error that if I want to call a virtual function of a C++ class from QML, I have to declare all of them in class hierarchy as Q_INVOKABLE otherwise I get an error of type:

> TypeError: Property 'X' of object X(0xXX) is not a function

I can't really find any documentation related to this, can someone point me towards it please? What about if I want to register a derived class type and instantiate it in QML, will it work? Are there any performance concerns related to declaring virtual functions as Q_INVOKABLE? At the moment, what I am doing is following (prototype).

```
class B : public QObject
{
public:
   virtual void foo();
}

class D : public B
{
public:
   Q_INVOKABLE virtual void foo();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Base * derived = new D;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("derived", d);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Missing Q_OBJECT macro?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Q_INVOKABLE`, you can declare your function under `slots` section:

```
class D : public B
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    virtual void foo();
}
```

Check out this link for detailed explanation:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Calling_Qt_class_methods_from_QML

Also, don't forget the Q_OBJECT macro in your classes.

**UPDATE**

Both `Q_INVOKABLE` and the `slots` keyword basically do the same thing. They "register" your function with Qt meta-system. The difference is, as you pointed out in the comment is that with `Q_INVOKABLE` you can return values.

In terms of virtual functions -- they work transparently, just like they do in regular C++.

In your example, since you are passing `Base*` pointer to QML, Qt meta-system needs to be "enabled" for this class by adding the `Q_OBJECT` macro and its `foo` function needs to be registered with `Q_INVOKABLE`.

You don't have to do that in the derived class. So your code would be:

```
class B : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE virtual void foo();
}

class D : public B
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Base * derived = new D;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("derived", d);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Following is a complete example that I modified from the above linked article. It uses `Q_INVOKABLE`, `slots` and `virtual` functions.

example.pro

```
QT += declarative

HEADERS += stringhelper.h
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

stringhelper.h

```
#ifndef STRINGHELPER_H
#define STRINGHELPER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

// outputs text, ignoring reverse
class StringHelper_Base : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    StringHelper_Base(QObject *parent = 0): QObject(parent) { }

    Q_INVOKABLE virtual QString echo(const QString &text) const {
        return text;
    }

public slots:
    virtual void toggleEcho(bool reverse) { (void)reverse; }
};

// outputs text with reversing
class StringHelper : public StringHelper_Base
{
public:
    StringHelper(QObject *parent = 0): StringHelper_Base(parent), reverse(false) { }

    QString echo(const QString &text) const {
        if(reverse == false) { return text; }

        QString reversed;
        for(QString::const_iterator it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); it++) {
            reversed.push_front(*it);
        }

        return reversed;
    }

    void toggleEcho(bool reverse) { this->reverse = reverse; }

protected:
    bool reverse;
};

#endif // STRINGHELPER_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>
#include "stringhelper.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    //StringHelper_Base* stringHelper = new StringHelper_Base();
    StringHelper_Base* stringHelper = new StringHelper();

    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("foo", stringHelper);
    view.setSource(QUrl("./ui.qml"));

    view.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 480);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: rect

    property string text: "Using Qt class to echo this"

    function updateUI() {
        foo.toggleEcho(button.pressed); // calling StringHelper::toggleEcho
        text.text = foo.echo(rect.text) // calling StringHelper::echo
    }

    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "black"

    Component.onCompleted: updateUI()

    Text {
        id: text
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "white"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: button

        property bool pressed: false

        width: 100; height: 40
        anchors.right: parent.right; anchors.rightMargin: 20
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom; anchors.bottomMargin: 20
        radius: 6
        color: pressed ? "gray" : "white"

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Reverse"
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: { button.pressed = !button.pressed; updateUI() }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know but the link still does't say anything about virtual functions and Q_INVOKABLE. I am just using virtual with Q_INVOKABLE right tnow.  I like the `public slots` way but sometime I have to return values which means I have to use methods.

Comment: @zadane, I updated the answer, hopefully it clarifies things for you

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained it really well and this is exactly what I was looking for. I changed my code accordingly and works perfect!